# How to shield the internals of a Lerna package, so other packages cannot import them?

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules, monorepo, lerna

I am working with a Lerna monorepo. I often see one package make imports from deep inside another package, for example:

```js
import { SomeType } from "@schema/folder/folder/file.ts"
```

This is undesirable, because sometimes we need to transform auto-generated types before exporting them via `index.d.ts`. This sometimes results in the wrong, non-transformed type being imported from deep inside the package.

I would like to somehow constrain the files/folders that one package exposes to the others, so such imports would not be possible:

```js
import { SomeType } from "@schema" // valid
import { SomeType2 } from "@schema/folder/folder/file.ts" // invalid
```

What are my options?

I am not sure what other info I can provide since I have little to no experience with this stuff.

Comment: You might be looking for [subpath `exports` in the *package.json*](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports). TypeScript [will also support this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#package-json-exports-imports-and-self-referencing) in v4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `eslint`, you can add a `no-restricted-imports` rule to the eslint settings of the package:

```
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": ["@schema/folder/*"]
      }
    ],
```

Comment: This will prevent yourself from importing that, but not other packages that don't run eslint with your package's settings.

Comment: @Bergi Which really is fine in the context of my question. I'm trying to constrain people working inside my monorepo, and I naturally have full control over eslint in every package of said monorepo. If then somebody else wants to include my package inside his and dig inside `dist/` for types/values, that really isn't my problem.